# Speed up plug-in datasource in ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, performance

Are there any tricks involved in getting plug-in data sources to run at higher speeds, similar to the built in types?  I've noticed that a simple plugin-data source will run many times slower than the equivelent data loaded from a shapefile or personal geodatabase, and the extra time seems to be mainly in the rendering phase.

Are there any tricks available to improve this in ArcObjects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect unmanaged C++ would be fastest.  It's not clear to me if this:

> This is a special interface that may
>   be implemented by the plug-in cursor
>   helper class of a plug-in data source.
>   IPlugInFastQueryValues cannot be
>   implemented in Visual Basic. Its
>   FastQueryValues method is more
>   efficient than the QueryValues method
>   on IPlugInCursorHelper.
>
> This interface is only appropriate for
>   plug-in data sources implemented in
>   C++.

... implies [IPluginFastQuery](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IPlugInFastQueryValues_Interface/002500000658000000/) won't work in C#.  Maybe the documentation is from the pre-.NET era.

Might be worth trying.  (I've never used it though).

Comment: IPluginFastQuery can be implemented in C#. The documentation in this case, indeed, does not take .NET languages into account.

Comment: Anyway, plugin data sources ARE slow, I guess there is not much you can do about that. This is an area of ArcGIS framework which has never been put into intensive use (do you know of any third-party plugins?) and as such has never been given enough attention performance-wise.

Comment: @petr k.: Esri's data interop extension uses it, as well as Safe's FME: http://www.safe.com/solutions/application/esri/index.php

Comment: That being said - I'd like to see how to implement IPluginFastQuery in C#.  It doesn't look possible without reverting to to C++, since you need to be able to deallocate BSTR references.  If you know of a sample, I'd **love** to see it.  @Kirk: Do you know if this interface really makes this much faster?

Comment: @Reed: sorry, not sure if it would make it much faster.  Since it is only used for copying the attributes (and not the geometry) the amount of improvement probably depends on how many attributes (fields) you have.